# Process dataframe by looping each dataframe using for loop

Tags: python, pandas

I try to perform some process on all Dataframe I have by using for loop by nothing changes.

Codes:

```
import pandas as pd

a = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3,4,5,6,7],
                 'b':[8,9,0,1,2,3,4]})
b = pd.DataFrame({'c':[1,2,3,4,5,6,7],
                 'b':[8,9,0,1,2,3,4]})

li = [a,b]
for i in li:
    'df_{}'.format(i) = i.rename(columns={'b':'test'})
```

Both a and b outputs:

```
    a   b
0   1   8
1   2   9
2   3   0
3   4   1
4   5   2
5   6   3
6   7   4

    c   b
0   1   8
1   2   9
2   3   0
3   4   1
4   5   2
5   6   3
6   7   4
```

Expected output:

```
    a   test
0   1   8
1   2   9
2   3   0
3   4   1
4   5   2
5   6   3
6   7   4

    c   test
0   1   8
1   2   9
2   3   0
3   4   1
4   5   2
5   6   3
6   7   4
```

can anyone point out what is wrong here? I try to use it on other dataset but nothing changes and I do not understand why. Please help.

Btw, I am wondering whether if I can make a different name for it like. above edited?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `inplace=True` in `rename`:

```
for i in li:
    i.rename(columns={'b':'test'}, inplace=True) # Without assignment
```

Output:

```
a.head()
   a  test
0  1     8
1  2     9
2  3     0
3  4     1
4  5     2

b.head()
   c  test
0  1     8
1  2     9
2  3     0
3  4     1
4  5     2
```

Comment: Thank you but I made some changes and wondering you can assist me on it? pls

Comment: @Anonymous Making dynamic variable name is simply a **bad** approach. Many good workaround can be found at [How do i create a variable number of variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373164/how-do-i-create-a-variable-number-of-variables)

Comment: Thanks and I try to use globals() but it wont work.

Answer (score 0):

rename creates a new instance.

instead try:

```
for i in li:
    i = i.rename(columns={'b':'test'}, inplace=True)
```

Comment: Thank you but I made some changes and wondering you can assist me on it? pls

Answer (score 0):

*(EDIT):*

It looks like the columns you're transforming are getting superpositioed on the copied object. The following workaround should solve this:

```
for i in li:
    f'df_{i}' = i.copy(deep=True)
    f'df_{i}' = f'df_{i}'.rename(columns={'b':'test'})
```

Comment: Thank you but I made some changes and wondering you can assist me on it? pls

Comment: Responded, take a look